# How to add Table Type as a Out Parameter to Dapper Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, dapper, out-parameters

I'm using dapper to connect to Oracle Database for my .Net Core Microservices application.

In a stored procedure, I have one out parameter like this.

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_PLAN_TEST
(
   ... other parameters goes here....
   P_PARENT_PLAN_ID           MFP_PLAN.PLAN_HEADER.PARENT_PLAN_ID%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
   OUT_PLAN_ID                OUT NUMBER,  
   O_ERR_CODE                 OUT ERR_CODE    
)
IS
```

Here, the **O_ERR_CODE** is of type **TABLE OF varchar2(200)**

Now, In my C# method, How I can pass such parameter?

```
public async Task<int> CreatePlanAsync(PlanHeader planHeader)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = _context.Database.GetOracleConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var _params = new DynamicParameters();
        _params.Add("P_ORG_ID", planHeader.OrgId, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
        ..... other parameters goes here.....
       _params.Add("O_ERR_CODE", null, <here i need to specify the type>, ParameterDirection.Output);
    }
}
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Do You use return dynamic object on return c#?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, You cannot return data in a table-valued parameter. Table-valued parameters are input-only; the OUTPUT keyword is not supported.